# How to validate the upload file contains tab delimited data using PHP? 

Tags: php, csv

I want to validate that an uploaded file is separated with tab delimiter. My file is not `.CSV`. Does anyone knows how to do this in PHP? Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450345/how-to-validate-csv-file

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: As long as the file content is in a csv format, the extension of the file should not matter. What code have you tried?

Comment: @BugFinder I am guessing nothing.  :-)

Comment: @BioLounge the filetype is determined by the MIME type or for something as simply as a csv file, as long as it's text you can parse it.  So you you just have to do checks on the file to make sure the file meets your definition of a 'csv' file

Comment: true, but as csv is also used as terminology for just a delimited file, wether thats commas, question marks, or tabs .. we really need a little more of a hint I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear what you are asking for (maybe you could post some examples) This might help you anyway:

Search for the tab character: `"\t"` The double quotes are important. If you have a list of tabbed items in a string and want to turn it into an array you can use [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/explode) and enter "\t" as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my code in this post:

[how to find out if csv file fields are tab delimited or comma delimited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395267/how-to-find-out-if-csv-file-fields-are-tab-delimited-or-comma-delimited/16500985#16500985)

Basically, you compare the number of tabs in each row. If every row of your CSV has the same number of tabs, then it is probably a tab delimited file. Please note, this will not be the case 100% of the time, it's a good starting point for validation.