# Check if CSV data is correct with javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I should check whether the data of a `csv` file are correct, if they are properly separated by commas even within a string quotes, I do not have to parse because that's already been done by others because the period in which the `csv` is used to create charts, I have to make only the verification of correctness of the data if user upload a file.

How can I do ?

This is the html code :

```
<!-- Adding CSV data to the document -->
<head>
  <script id="cur_data" type="text/csv">
    Russian Federation, Italy, France, Luxembourg, Greece, Japan, Others
    293, 302, 91, 7, 7, 7, 53
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Sections -->
  <div class="section">
    <h1>Figures</h1>
      <div id="figure_1" class="picture">
        <p class="img_block">
          <img src="#cur_data" class="horizontal_bar_chart" alt="Let's graph it!"></img>
        </p>
        <p class="caption">Caption of the figure.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450345/how-to-validate-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var data = '293, 302, 91, 7, 7, 7, 53'

var valid = !!data.match(/,/)
```

or using `String.split` should better

e.g. assuming your "valid" data must contains 7 comma

```
var valid = data.split(',').length - 1 === 7
```

Comment: thanks,but my teacher told me to do the checking on a .csv file , there are many libraries that allow these checks